# How to draw a certain PDF

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, distributions

Here `Dist` is the PDF. I need to draw it. Can someone suggest me a way to do it?

```
A = 0.5;
α = 4;
μ =  1.0000;
k = 0;
τ = 1;
δ = 1/2;
m = 1;

s[rd_] := (μ rd^α)/Pm;

LocalMeanPowerInLinear = 1;
LocalMeanPowerIndB = Log10[LocalMeanPowerInLinear]*10;
β = LocalMeanPowerIndB*Log[10]/10;

StdSindB = 8;
σ = StdSindB*Log[10]/10;

G[t_] := 
  Exp[-1/2*Exp[-Sqrt[2]*σ*t - β]*m*x^2]*(Exp[Sqrt[2]*σ*t + β])^(-m);

T = 
  {3.4362, 2.5327, 1.7567, 1.0366, 0.3429, 
   -0.3429, -1.0366, -1.7567, -2.5327, -3.4362};
W = 
  {0.0000, 0.0013, 0.0339, 0.2401, 0.6109, 
   0.6109, 0.2401, 0.0339, 0.0013, 0.0000};

f[x_] = 
  (1 - A)*FullSimplify[(1 + k)*Exp[-k]*x/τ*Exp[-(1 + k)*x^2/(2*τ)]*
    BesselJ[0, Sqrt[2*k*(1+k)/τ]*x]] + 
  A*x^(2*m - 1)/(2^(m - 1)*Sqrt[π]*Gamma[m])*W.(G /@ T);

Dist = TransformedDistribution[x^2/2,
x \[Distributed] ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT : Made `A` variable per OP's comment.

```
Clear[A, f, Dist]

α = 4;
μ = 1;
k = 0;
τ = 1;
δ = 1/2;
m = 1;
s[rd_] := (μ rd^α)/Pm;
LocalMeanPowerInLinear = 1;
LocalMeanPowerIndB = Log10[LocalMeanPowerInLinear]*10;
β = LocalMeanPowerIndB*Log[10]/10;
StdSindB = 8;
σ = StdSindB*Log[10]/10;
G[t_] := Exp[-1/2*Exp[-Sqrt[2]*σ*t - β]*m*
     x^2]*(Exp[Sqrt[2]*σ*t + β])^(-m);
T = {3.4362, 2.5327, 1.7567, 1.0366, 
   0.3429, -0.3429, -1.0366, -1.7567, -2.5327, -3.4362};
W = {0.0000, 0.0013, 0.0339, 0.2401, 0.6109, 0.6109, 0.2401, 0.0339, 0.0013, 
   0.0000};

f[x_, A_: 1/2] := (1 - A)*
    FullSimplify[(1 + k)*Exp[-k]*x/\[Tau]*
      Exp[-(1 + k)*x^2/(2*\[Tau])]*
      BesselJ[0, Sqrt[2*k*(1 + k)/\[Tau]]*x]] + 
   A*x^(2*m - 1)/(2^(m - 1)*Sqrt[\[Pi]]*Gamma[m])*W.(G /@ T);

Dist[A_: 1/2] := 
  TransformedDistribution[x^2/2, 
   x \[Distributed] 
    ProbabilityDistribution[f[x, A], {x, 0, Infinity}]];
```

`Dist` is a distribution not a `PDF`. To `Plot` the `PDF` of the distribution for various values of `A` use

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[
   Tooltip[PDF[Dist[A], x], A],
   {A, {1/4, 1/2, 1}}],
 {x, 0, 5},
 PlotRange -> {0, 1},
 PlotLegends -> (StringForm["A = ``", #] & /@ {1/4, 1/2, 1})]
```

[image]

Or

```
LogPlot[Evaluate@
  Table[
   Tooltip[PDF[Dist[A], x], A],
   {A, {1/4, 1/2, 1}}],
 {x, 0, 100},
 PlotRange -> {10^-5, 1},
 PlotLegends -> (StringForm["A = ``", #] & /@ {1/4, 1/2, 1})]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It works very fine. How about if I want to draw the PDF f[x_] (the second last line of my code)? I tried : 'Plot[Evaluate@ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}], PlotRange -> {0, 1}]' , but it does not work!

Comment: and if I want to draw the PDFs for a range of values of $A$ (first parameter in my code) and put them together, how I should do it?

Comment: @SresthaNarayanan - you have the wrong syntax for plotting the PDF of `f`.  Plot[Evaluate@PDF[ProbabilityDistribution[f[x], {x, 0, Infinity}], x], {x, 0, 6}]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What does it mean: f[x_, A_: 1/2]. I know that f[x_, A_] is a function of two arguments, namely, x and A. Is it somewhat default value of A? Also, please suggest me to plot f[x] for different values of A. I tried but could not make it.

Comment: @SresthaNarayanan - read the documentation for [Optional](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Optional.html). For question about plotting `f` open a new question and post the code that you tried.